# C#->Python SVN Pre-Commit Hook: How to access svn:keywords?

Tags: c#, python, svn, pre-commit-hook

I've been asked to re-add an extra check to our pre-commit hook to ensure svn:keywords are set on certain paths in our repos (e.g. scripts that need the Revision and URL values injecting). We had a clunky pre-commit hook written in C# using SharpSvn doing this originally, but we've migrated our SVN server to Linux, so I rewrote the hook in Python. It has most of the functionality, but I missed out the keyword checking.

In C#, the code used is like so:

```
SvnPropertyCollection propCollection;
svnLookClient.GetPropertyList(svnHookArgs.LookOrigin, item.Path, out propCollection);
....
if (item.Path.Contains("some path") && !propCollection.Contains("svn:keywords"))
{ /*Fail the commit here*/ }
```

I've found out the hard way that the transaction properties do not contain svn:keywords, even when I make a commit where all I have done is set them; calling `svn.fs.svn_fs_txn_proplist` on the transaction gives me the following properties:

- svn:log
- svn:txn-client-compat-version
- svn:txn-user-agent
- svn:author
- svn:date

My Python code looks like this:

```
def check_keywords_are_set(transaction, repos_name):
  commit_has_source_files = False
  source_extensions = ('.sql', '.hlr') #Only care about source files
  transaction_root = svn.fs.svn_fs_txn_root(transaction)

  changed_paths = svn.fs.paths_changed(transaction_root)
  for path, change in changed_paths.iteritems():
    if repos_name == 'repo1' or (repos_name == 'repo2' and ('some path' in path): #These are the paths I want to enforce keywords being set on
    if path.endswith(source_extensions):
      commit_has_source_files = True
  if not commit_has_source_files:
    return True
  #debugging code here:
  transaction_props = svn.fs.svn_fs_txn_proplist(transaction)
  sys.stdout.write('Transaction prop list:\n{0}\n'.format(transaction_props))
  #end debugging

  keywords = svn.fs.svn_fs_txn_prop(transaction, 'svn:keywords')
  #keywords is always None
```

Looking back at the C# code, I can see references to svnlook, so I guess I'll have to use this. However, I'm getting confused between 'revision properties' and all other 'properties'. I'm also not sure how to write this so that if a developer is adding the missing keywords to files within a folder that should have them, or we're creating a new folder where this will later be enforced, it won't throw a false negative. The documentation for doing this in Python is quite poor and generally requires reading the C API source, which unfortunately I cannot get my head around (I am not a C developer), let alone translate into Python. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.